RAG model chat history does not work properly
I am currently trying to develop a sample project by learning RAG. In this code, I aim to chat with a document in Pinecone and while doing this, I try to keep the spoken conversations. These chat histories are successfully kept in a list. But when I want to ask the model something about this past, it answers as if I asked it for the first time. Here's the code:
import time
from typing import Dict, Optional

import streamlit as st
from langchain_community.vectorstores.pinecone import Pinecone as LangChainPinecone
from langchain_openai.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain_openai.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from pinecone import Pinecone
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
import os

INDEX_NAME = "index-name"
PROMPT_TEMPLATE = """
Question:
"""
NUM_RETRIEVED_DOCS = 5
TEMPERATURE = 0.3
CONVERSATION_MEMORY_SIZE = 5


def initialize_pinecone_client(api_key: str) -> Pinecone:
    return Pinecone(api_key=api_key)


def initialize_session_state():
    if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.chat_history = []


def get_response(user_query: str, openai_api_key: str) -> Dict[str, Optional[str]]:
    try:
        initialize_session_state()

        full_query = PROMPT_TEMPLATE + user_query
        pc_client = initialize_pinecone_client(api_key=st.secrets["pinecone_api_key"])

        embedding_model = OpenAIEmbeddings(model="text-embedding-3-large", openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
        index = pc_client.Index(INDEX_NAME)

        time.sleep(1)

        index.describe_index_stats()
        conversation_memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

        vectorstore = LangChainPinecone(index=index, embedding=embedding_model, text_key="context")
        llm = OpenAI(temperature=TEMPERATURE, openai_api_key=openai_api_key)
        retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever(search_type="similarity", search_kwargs={"k": NUM_RETRIEVED_DOCS})

        qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(llm=llm,
                                                         retriever=retriever,
                                                         memory=conversation_memory)


        # update conversation memory
        chat_history = st.session_state.chat_history
        while True:
            result = qa_chain({'question': full_query, 'chat_history': chat_history})
            print(chat_history)

            response = result['answer']
            chat_history.append((full_query, response))
            st.session_state.chat_history = chat_history
            return {'result': result, 'chat_history': chat_history}
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return {"answer": "An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again later.", "sources": None}


user_query = st.text_area("Enter your question here:")

if st.button("Get Response"):
    if user_query:
        response = get_response(user_query, openai_api_key=st.secrets["openai_api_key"])
        # print(response)
        st.write("Answer:", response['result'].get("answer", "No answer found."))
        sources = response['result'].get("sources")
        if sources:
            st.write("Source:", os.path.basename(sources))
        else:
            st.write("No specific source cited.")

        st.write("Chat History:")
        for i, (question, answer) in enumerate(response['chat_history']):
            st.write(f"Turn {i + 1}:")
            st.write(f"Q: {question}")
            st.write(f"A: {answer}")
            st.write("---")
    else:
        st.error("Please enter a question.")

Here's the issue that i mentioned above:
Turn 1:
Q: Question: What's that document related about?
A: The document is related to the Amended and Restated Agreement for Research & Development Alliance on Triex Module Technology between The Research Foundation for the State University of New York and Silevo, Inc.

Turn 2:
Q: Question: What did i ask you before?
A: I don't know, I am an AI and I do not have the ability to remember previous questions.
I don't know where I made a mistake. I'll be happy if you can help me. Thanks

I am facing similar problem. Did you solve this?

unfortunately no @Anonymous
